# reactRedux Global State change

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Ok, im trying to create a global state.

where parent object get change and children will know the change.

right now im reloading the page which i dont like.

in my `APP` i have

```
 state = {
        userIsLogged: true
    }
```

then i have the following code below

```
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact>
                        <Home />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/info">
                        <Info />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/search">
                        <Search />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login">
                        <Login />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/favorit">
                        <Favorit />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/chapter">
                        <Chapter />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
```

Now when `userIsLogged` is changed, i want reRender the Current Page eg favorit or search etc.

I have locked into store but im struggling to understand it.

Any one like to explain it simple or is there any other way doing it.

Comment: you have to use selectors inside the components to make them re-render on state change.

Comment: Yes please write a simple example please

Comment: Not much to tell from your code currently, show us more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const App = (props) => {

  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  );
  if (props.isAuth) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/favourite" component={Favourite} />
        <Route path="/search" component={Search} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
  return routes;
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuth: state.userIsLogged
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

So whenever the `userIsLogged` changes the component re-renders because the `isAuth` prop changes. Now how you use that prop and what components or routes you use is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do something like this in the component:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    userData: state.userIsLogged
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Favorit);
```

Now favorit has the data in its props.

```js
export default function Favorit(props) {
  console.log(props.userData) // here it is
}
```

Though I recommend using, reselect for performance reasons.
you can define a function like this in the file you have state:

```js
const selectUserIsLogged = state => state.userIsLogged
```

And then in component:

```js
import {selectUserIsLogged} from '..';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
// inside the component function
const userIsLogged = useSelector(selectUserIsLogged)
```

Comment: Yes but i want to make changes selectUserIsLogged how will children get the changes. im not intressted in constant value. eg make change to selectUserIsLogged Render() will trigger in children

Comment: @Alen.Toma React will re-render the component if `userIsLogged` is being used in a component and is changed.

Comment: yeah it would be triggered automatically provided you change state using dispatch.